# usage of tf.gather to index lists containing non-Tensor types

Tags: python, list, tensorflow

Consider the following code. I'd like to know how I can gather non-Tensor types from a list.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Point(tf.experimental.ExtensionType):
    xx: tf.Tensor
    def __init__(self,xx):
        self.xx = xx
        super().__init__()

list1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4] 
list2 = [ Point(1), Point(2), Point(3), Point(4) ]

# this works
out1 = tf.gather(list1,[0,2])
print('First gather ',out1)

# this throws: ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (Point(xx=<tf.Tensor:
# shape=(), dtype=int32, numpy=1>)) with an unsupported type
# (<class '__main__.Point'>) to a Tensor.

out2 = tf.gather(list2,[0,2])
print('Second gather ',out2)
```

Answer (score 1):

### My Answer

It is easy. Convert `Point` list to `Tensor` list.

### My Example

```py
import tensorflow as tf


class Point(tf.experimental.ExtensionType):
    xx: tf.Tensor

    def __init__(self, xx):
        self.xx = xx
        super().__init__()


list2 = [Point(1), Point(2), Point(3), Point(4)]


out2 = tf.gather([x.xx for x in list2], [0, 2])
print('Second gather ', out2)
# > Second gather  tf.Tensor([1 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: is it possible to do this without converting to a Tensor list? I was hoping that since I derived from ExtensionType, I wouldn't have to do that.

Comment: you should also convert them in your derived class

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

[`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) is specifically designed to work with tensors or lists that can be converted to tensors.

`tf.gather(list1, [0, 2])` works because `list1` contains integers which tensorflow can interpret as a tensor.

However, `list2` contains custom objects of type `Point` whcih tensorflow does not understand. Thus, using `tf.gather` directly on `list2` raises the observed error.

To gather elements from a list of non-tensor types, like custom objects, you can use a list comprehension.

E.g.

```py
indices = [0,2]
out2 - [list2[i] for i in indices]
```

If you must stick to TensorFlow functions for some reason, the current design of the Point class, direct TensorFlow operations like `tf.gather` aren't the ideal choice.

`tf.experimental.ExtensionType` was introduced to allow user-defined classes to behave like tensorflow natives types, but this is still experimental and may not work with all operations.

The error you are seeing indicates that the `tf.gather` operation foes not recognize `Point` as a tensor-like object.

One potential workaround without converting the whole list into tensors might be to implement the desired behavior directly on the `Point` class.

e.g.

```py
class Point(tf.experimental.ExtensionType):
    xx: tf.Tensor
    
    def __init__(self, xx):
        self.xx = xx
        super().__init__()

    @classmethod
    def gather(cls, points, indices):
        return [points[i] for i in indices]

list2 = [Point(1), Point(2), Point(3), Point(4)]

# Using the gather method of Point class
out2 = Point.gather(list2, [0,2])
print('Second gather ', out2)
```

the `gather` method on `Point` essentially replicates the list comprehension, but does not utilize tensorflow's computational graph capabilities.

over time `ExtensionType` may be further refined allowing for a more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather), it expects a **tensor** as input to work with. If we pass list (i.e. `list1`, it will be converted to tensor as well. But in your case, each item in `list2` is an object of `Point` class which tensorflow unable to interpret. In that case, you may convert each item to list or tensor in oder to use it with `tf.gather`.

```py
inputs = tf.convert_to_tensor(
    [point.xx.numpy() for point in list2]
)
ouput = tf.gather(tensor2, [0, 2])
ouput 
tf.Tensor([1 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
```